# How to check and replace exist file property in Java?

Tags: java

My file name will be `tablename_current date.csv`.

In the first time, it will create a new file, but after that, when having the same table name, it will rewrite the file created the first time and only change the current date.

```
private String filePath;
private String downloadToDirectory;

public void init() {
    logWriter = new LogWriter("FileTransferCommand", LogWriter.DEBUG);

    // Declare the properties file.
    InputStream is = null;
    Properties dbProps = new Properties();

    try {
        is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fileTransfer.properties");
        dbProps.load(is);

        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String prop1 = "equity_ftp"; String prop2 = "download_dir";
        if(OS.indexOf("WIN")>=0){
                prop1 = prop1 + "_win32";
                prop2 = prop2 + "_win32";
        }

        filePath = dbProps.getProperty(prop1);
        downloadToDirectory = dbProps.getProperty(prop2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logWriter.log("init Exception : " +e.getMessage(), LogWriter.ERROR);
    }finally{
        try {
            if(is!=null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            is=null;
        } 
    }

    logWriter.log("FileTransferCommand object is created ($Revision: 1.12 $)", LogWriter.INFO);
}

private boolean writeToFile(String[] downloadedResult, FileTransferBean fileTransferBean, FileTransferBean[] fileTransferList, List errors, HttpServletRequest req){

    boolean isOK = false;
    String userAgent = FormUtil.returnString(req.getHeader("HTTP_USER_AGENT"));
    //default to windows
    String linebreak = "\r\n";
    if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("nix") >= 0 || userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("nux") >= 0 || userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("x11") >= 0){
        //unix family
        linebreak = "\n";
    }else if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        //mac
        linebreak = "\r";
    }
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try{
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(downloadToDirectory+fileTransferBean.getTargetFile())));
        if (downloadedResult != null && downloadedResult.length > 0){
            if (fileTransferBean.getShowDelim().equals("1")){
                FileTransferBean fileBean = new FileTransferBean();
                for (int a=0; a < fileTransferList.length; a++) {
                    fileBean = fileTransferList[a];
                    out.print(fileBean.getStr2());
                    if (a < fileTransferList.length-1) out.print(",");
                }
                out.print(linebreak);
                //if(isUnix()) out.println("\r");
                //else out.println();
            }    
            for (int z=0; z<downloadedResult.length; z++) {
                out.print(downloadedResult[z].trim());
                out.print(linebreak);
                //if(isUnix()) out.println("\r");
                //else out.println();
            }
        }else{
            logWriter.log(">>>No record from : "+fileTransferBean.getTableName(), LogWriter.DEBUG);
        }
        out.flush();
        isOK = true;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logWriter.log("writeToFile IOException : " +ioe.getMessage(), LogWriter.ERROR);
        errors.add("Error while downloading file");
        isOK = false;
    }finally{
        if(out!=null)
            out.close();
        out = null;
    }
    return isOK;
}
```

How can I do it?

This code only creates the new file, but not rewrite again when the table name is the same and replace the current date.

Comment: Has the date changed? Your code should "rewrite again".

Comment: It not exactly sure for me what do you want to achieve. Do you want to rewroite the file after every run? or append to it's end?